# how to add month abbr to string and create Dynamic string using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I want make string Dynamic with Month abbr in it.**

for eg.

**01]** In current Month (Means Sep) it will print below string.

i.e: payment links that are yet to be renewed for the month of **Aug** to **Oct 2022**

**02]** In Next Month (Means Oct) it will print below string.

i.e: payment links that are yet to be renewed for the month of **Sep** to **Nov 2022**

Comment: f-strings and datetime are the things you need to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You ignore the corner cases. For instance, if current month is Dec. 2022, what you expect should be `Nov. 2022 to Jan. 2023`, not `Nov. to Jan. 2022`.
2. You can use `dateutil`

```
import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

now = datetime.date.today()
prev_month = now - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
next_month = now + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
print(f"payment links that are yet to be renewed for the month of {prev_month.strftime('%b %Y')} to {next_month.strftime('%b %Y')}")
```